# Is there a way to get extraglobs-like behavior when invoking doctests through nosetests?

Tags: python, testing, nose, doctest

At the bottom of a Python module, I have:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    import hgvs.dataproviders.uta
    doctest.testmod(extraglobs={'hdp': hgvs.dataproviders.uta.connect()})
```

The effect of the extraglobs bit is to create an instance of a database connection and expose it to tests as a variable `hdp`, like this:

```
class EasyVariantMapper(VariantMapper):
    """Provides simplified variant mapping for a single assembly and
    ...
    >>> evm = EasyVariantMapper(hdp)
    >>> evm._alt_ac_for_tx_ac('NM_000552.3')
    ['NC_000012.11']

    """
```

That works just dandy when I invoke doctests with `python hgvs/variantmapper.py` because the tests are invoked with the extraglobs initialization.

However, I get errors due to hdp being undefined when I invoke with `nosetests --with-doctest` or `python -m doctest hgvs/variantmapper.py` because those invocations doesn't use the extraglobs.

How does one write doctests that use an initialized state and are valid under both the doctest and nose frameworks? (http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_doctest_fixtures/doctest_fixtures.html was not helpful to me.)

Comment: Nice tricks. To your question: I am afraid, you have to do the import and `doctest.testmod(..` out of `if __name__ == "__main__":` block. Not sure it would help, but I cannot imagine other way.